# Как изменить форму края в меню?

Tags: html, css3, вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать края в меню такими, как на фото(обведено красным)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div.square{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: gray;
}
div.square:before{
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 50px solid transparent;
 border-left: 25px solid white;
 border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

С помощью before и after немного криво сделал но смысл я думаю ты понял

Answer (score 0):

Данный пример не будет работать в IE и EDGE

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 90% 50%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%, 10% 50%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```